# Can anyone suggest a limit holdem training app for Android?

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds, probability

First time poster in this part of the world, so apologies if I've posted this in the wrong area.

In short; I used to play a lot of Poker in University over a decade ago, and then continued to play for a couple of years after graduating (reasonably well and then work got in the way). I haven't played a meaningful game in years and am just looking to sharpen up my skills, and perecentages a touch before I consider playing "live" again.

I've found a couple of fun apps (I like having things that stretch the mind on my mobile for when you have a quiet 15 mins), but am looking for something a bit more.

In short, I have used Equity Battle, to get my numbers on hands a bit sharper;
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.equitybattle&hl=en

and then tried WPT Trainer briefly (before realising it was essentially Insta Poker without Hand Packs) before switching to Insta Poker;

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.gamoz.instapoker&hl=en

Which is fun, but it is based on No-Limit and occasionally just to prove a point you have to do really questionable things to get the right answer (playing behind someone, they bet out on the turn, we were obviously beat with the cards on the table, but they suggested a call to force the situation on the river - the idea was to adopt a tight-agressive image etc.).

Ideally, I think I am after something like Equity Battle, but limit and multi-handed (if that makes sense). I'm totally not worried about any kind of "live play" or "play money" kind of play, I'm just keen to improve my theory and sharpen up my situational play (and have a bit of fun as well).

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions,

Comment: You are pointed in exactly the right direction. May I ask why you feel you need an app? Play some FLHE. You seem to know what you're looking for, you seem to understand what the (previous) app is telling you and why it would suggest particular moves in particular spots. 
The fact that you are already thinking steps ahead of one app says to me you are ready to go think one step ahead at the tables.

Comment: @Snipe apologies for the late response. Found an app that I like "Bots Don't Bluff" which does just what I needed - it is Pot Limit Hold'em against 4 AI players. In short it's allowed me to just get a feel for play again & reading others e.g. you've raised on the turn, but I'm still good/now have the "nuts" & am going all in etc. or AK o/s on the button against a pre-flop raise to the big blind, I'm folding etc.

Comment: You might also have asked at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/